# Controlling x-axis label format for time series plots - R

Tags: r, plot, timestamp, time-series

Is there a way force R to print time stamps as %m/%d/%Y on graphs? When I have short (<7 days) of data it prints as days of the week as below?

```
plot(station_171$datetime, station_171$stageheight, pch=ifelse(station_171$outcode ==122,24,21), col="black", bg=ifelse(station_171$outcode ==122,"red","NA")
     , xlab = "",xlim = c(min(station_101_7$datetime),max(station_101_7$datetime)), ylab = "")
legend("topright","171", bty = "n", cex=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format the axis using `axis.POSIXct` as seen below:

```
axis.POSIXct(1,station_171$datetime, format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%S')
```

One should also make sure to include the `xaxt='n'` in the plot function to avoid double printing the x-axis labels.